# sqlalchemy 1 to many relationship

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

i tried to implement a simple sqlalchemy table relationship

so, I have below model:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    UserID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    FirstName = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    LastName = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)

    #others column

    Tokens = db.relationship('Token', backref='Token.UserID', primaryjoin='User.UserID==Token.UserID', lazy='dynamic')

    #bla... other codes
```

and

```
class Token(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user_tokens"
    TokenID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    UserID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.UserID'))
    Token = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)

    #others column

    #bla... other codes
```

and I do query:

```
user = User.query.filter(User.UserID).first()
```

problem: when i tried to access:

```
print(user.Tokens.UserID)
# or
print(user.Tokens.Token)
```

I always received:

> 'AppenderBaseQuery' object has no attribute 'UserID' / 'Token'

What am I missing here?

Comment: What does it mean, to you, to print the UserID of a *collection* of tokens? (As opposed to a single token)

Comment: A user can have many tokens, so trying to access a user's tokens relationship as a scalar seems illogical. You've also configured the relationship as dynamic, so the relationship attribute is actually a query object with added behavior.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart the print is more for test to see if i can get the result, and yes, 1 user could have many Tokens.

Comment: @IljaEverilä - so how am I suppose to do?

Comment: First rename your backref. It'd seem you've mixed it with something else. The backref is a handy way of automating the creation of a relationship attribute at the other end, and the argument value in this case should be just the name for the attribute, for example "user" or "User". You should not need to define the primary join. It should be automatically deduced from your foreign key definition.  In order to access a user's tokens through a dynamic relationship either take slices of the query, or `user.Tokens.all()` and do what you will with the resulting list.

Comment: And most importantly, read the related docs: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/collections.html#dynamic-relationship-loaders

Comment: Thank you, it works! is there a way for me to get 1 paticular token based on the Tokens.value? `Tokens.all()` will giving me all tokens and i have to fo for loop to check `if token.value = look_up`. Is there a way to do it something like: `user.Tokens.filter (user.Tokens.token.value==look_up)` <- this giving me error... and you can write in answer i will mark as answer thanks for your kind help!