# SQLAlchemy finds record from relational query result based on certain attribute/column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have DB model with 1 to many relationship on 2 diffrent tables.

the relationship is working fine and I manage to query all:

```
items = user.Items.all()
for item in items :
    print('>>>>> TEST: %s <<<<<', item.name)
    # I can iterate item.name here
```

i tried to find/grab item based on `item.name` (could be more than one or None)
above code is work fine, and i could just run through the loop to find the item that i want. however, i believe there is a better way to achieve this, rather than i should iterate the record 1 by one and do if comparison.

i have tried:

```
item = user.Items.filter(user.Items.Name == needle)
```

and it throwing me error:

> 'AppenderBaseQuery' object has no attribute 'Name'

question: is there a single statement to find a record based on certain attribute/column value (not ID)?

Comment: Yes. Query using the Item model, not the relationship attribute of user. `Item.Name == needle` or such. Guessing since you've not included the models. [Again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44607363/sqlalchemy-1-to-many-relationship) I'd recommend reading the docs and giving them some thought. The key point you seem to struggle with is that the relationship attribute itself is a Query object, not the related model or some such, when configured to be dynamic.

Comment: how to get Item model? i only have user model with Items relationship inside. if i do user.Items.all() it will give me the list of all of the Items that this particular user has. and from that list, i would like to grab/catch the item based on its name (without doing for loop).

Comment: Surely you've defined the model class Item or similar somewhere. The one you've referenced either directly or lazily in the relationship definition.

Comment: ahhh, I got it, i just need to import the Item Model and reference it in Filter arguments - `user.Items.filter(Item.Name == 'Needle').first()` ... Thank You!

Comment: You could consider adding it as an answer to your own question.